# Let $Y ∼ U[0, 1]$, and let $X_n = Y^n$. Prove that $X_n\to 0$ in probability.

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $Y ∼ U[0, 1]$, and let $X_n = Y^n$. Prove that $X_n\to 0$ in probability.

I guess I need to use $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n − Y| ≥ \epsilon) = 0.
$

Comment: What is $Y_n$? You only defined $Y$...

Comment: Sorry it should be Xn = Y^n

Comment: Did you try calculating $P(|X_n-Y|\geq \epsilon)$?

Comment: Please note that the body of the question should contain the question itself. You should also explain some context, what your approach was so it is easier for people to understand what part of the question you have problems with. Also, your question should be formatted in MathJax, see here for a tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 6):

Since $0<Y<1$ almost surely we have $X_n=Y^{n} \to 0$ almost surely. Convergence with probability $1$ implies convergence in probability. Aliter: $P\{X_n > \epsilon\}=P\{Y >\epsilon^{1/n}\}=1-\epsilon^{1/n} \to 1-1= 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $X_n$ converges to $0$ and not to $Y$, so you need to show that $$P(|X_n-0|\ge\epsilon)\to 0$$ 
and not $P(|X_n-Y|\ge \epsilon)\to0$. You have that 
$$P(|X_n-0|\ge \epsilon)=P(X_n\ge \epsilon)=P(Y^n\ge \epsilon)=P(Y\ge \epsilon^{1/n})=\int_{\epsilon^{1/n}}^1dt=1-\epsilon^{1/n}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P[Y^n>\varepsilon]=0
\end{align*}

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P[Y^n>\varepsilon]&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P[Y>\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}]\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{Y} (\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}})\\
&=1-F_Y(1)\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Which proves convergence in distribution. In this case we can also prove almost sure convergence because for any $\omega\in\Omega$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y(\omega)^n=0$ unless $Y(\omega)=1$ so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[\lim_{n\to\infty} Y^n = 0] &= 1-\mathbb{P}[Y=1]\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Almost sure convergence gives you convergence in probability.